# Notification message seems to be empty when app is on foreground

Tags: android, push-notification, dart, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have configured `firebase-messaging` and `flutter_local_notifications` to be able to show show push notifications both when app is in foreground and in background. However, when `onMessage` is triggered with the app on foreground, the message itself seems to be empty.

Configuration:

```
FirebaseMessaging fcm = FirebaseMessaging();

flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

var initializationSettingsAndroid =
AndroidInitializationSettings('drawable/ic_stat');

var initializationSettingsIOS = IOSInitializationSettings();

var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
    initializationSettingsAndroid, initializationSettingsIOS);

flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
    selectNotification: (String payload) async {});


fcm.configure(
  onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> msg) {
    print("On launch $msg");
    showNotification(msg);
  },
  onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> msg) {
    print("On resume $msg");
    showNotification(msg);
  },
  onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> msg) {
    print("On message $msg");
    showNotification(msg);
  },
);
```

Handler:

```
void showNotification(Map<String, dynamic> msg) async{
  print(msg);
  var notificationsChannel = new AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'my_package',
      'my_organization',
      'notification_channel',
      importance: Importance.Max,
      priority: Priority.High);

  var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = new IOSNotificationDetails();

  var platformChannelSpecifics = new NotificationDetails(
      notificationsChannel, iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      0, msg['title'], msg['body'], platformChannelSpecifics,);

  }
```

Log when app in foreground:

```
W/FirebaseMessaging(10901): Error while parsing timestamp in GCM event
W/FirebaseMessaging(10901): java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
W/FirebaseMessaging(10901):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:483)
W/FirebaseMessaging(10901):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:556)
W/FirebaseMessaging(10901):     at com.google.firebase.messaging.zzb.zzc(Unknown Source)
W/FirebaseMessaging(10901):     at com.google.firebase.messaging.zzb.zze(Unknown Source)
W/FirebaseMessaging(10901):     at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzd(Unknown Source)
W/FirebaseMessaging(10901):     at com.google.firebase.iid.zzc.run(Unknown Source)
W/FirebaseMessaging(10901):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
W/FirebaseMessaging(10901):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
W/FirebaseMessaging(10901):     at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(Unknown Source)
W/FirebaseMessaging(10901):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
W/FirebaseMessaging(10901): Error while parsing timestamp in GCM event
W/FirebaseMessaging(10901): java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
W/FirebaseMessaging(10901):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:483)
W/FirebaseMessaging(10901):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:556)
W/FirebaseMessaging(10901):     at com.google.firebase.messaging.zzb.zzc(Unknown Source)
W/FirebaseMessaging(10901):     at com.google.firebase.messaging.zzb.zzh(Unknown Source)
W/FirebaseMessaging(10901):     at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzd(Unknown Source)
W/FirebaseMessaging(10901):     at com.google.firebase.iid.zzc.run(Unknown Source)
W/FirebaseMessaging(10901):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
W/FirebaseMessaging(10901):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
W/FirebaseMessaging(10901):     at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(Unknown Source)
W/FirebaseMessaging(10901):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
I/flutter (10901): On message {}
I/flutter (10901): {}
E/flutter (10901): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(181)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
E/flutter (10901): NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
E/flutter (10901): Receiver: null
E/flutter (10901): Tried calling: []("title")
```

However, when the app is in background, the notification is delivered directly to the system tray and it isn't empty
[(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EM2n.jpg).

Here's my flutter doctor output:

```
    [✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.8.2, on Mac OS X 10.13.5 17F77, locale es-ES)
    • Flutter version 0.8.2 at /Users/alex/Documents/Development/flutter
    • Framework revision 5ab9e70727 (3 weeks ago), 2018-09-07 12:33:05 -0700
    • Engine revision 58a1894a1c
    • Dart version 2.1.0-dev.3.1.flutter-760a9690c2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/alex/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-27, build-tools 27.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/alex/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 9.4.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 9.4.1, Build version 9F2000
    • ios-deploy 1.9.2
    • CocoaPods version 1.5.3

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 26.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 173.4700
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2018.1.1)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app
    • Flutter plugin version 26.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 181.4445.29

[✓] VS Code (version 1.27.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 2.18.0

[✓] Connected devices (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 7.0 (API 24) (emulator)

• No issues found!
```

Maybe this has something to do with how firebase messages work?

Comment: Are you using the latest firebase_messaging plugin version? https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19004

Comment: Notification is only shown when the app is in background. If you want to pass a message to the app, you need to use the `data` section.

Comment: Wasn't using latest version. I presume there were deprecation problems. Thanks.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer  can i not show firebase notification when the app is on foreground?

Comment: Sure. There are several local notification packages in pub.dartlang.org that can do that. The firebase_messages package does it not by itself.

Comment: @FunnyStunny did you solve this?

Comment: @Nbn i solved it by updating the plugins to their latest versions. And this is already old, so your issue may not be related to what I had back then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by updating (1)[`firebase-messaging`](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) and (2)[`flutter_local_notifications`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) to their latest versions.

Comment: I tried upgrading to the latest version but still its not working.